# triggering_frequency can only be used with FILE_LOADS method of writing to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Unable to set triggering_frequency for Dataflow Streaming job.

```
transformed | 'Write' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
          known_args.target_table,
          schema=schema,
          create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
          write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
          method=bigquery.WriteToBigQuery.Method.FILE_LOADS,
          triggering_frequency=5
          )

Error: triggering_frequency can only be used with FILE_LOADS method of writing to BigQuery
```

Comment: This is a bug. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. The `WriteToBigQuery` transform has a couple implementations - and the one that supports file loads in streaming is fairly new, thus it is masked behind an experiment.

So: To activate this, please pass `use_beam_bq_sink` as an experiment, like so: `--experiments use_beam_bq_sink`.

Comment: Thank you Pablo. Found it on SDK as well https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L1128

Comment: is this stil l the case? I am still getting the error, using version 2.22.0 of beam with `--experiments=use_beam_bq_sink`

Answer (score 3):

We are still seeing this issue some 9 months later however. Is the fix still to use the `experiments=use_beam_bq_sink` (because it looks to not be working on our end just now)..