# Dataflow / BigQuery FILE_LOADS: Job did not reach to a terminal state after waiting indefinitely

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have following pipeline

```
 with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:

        (
                p
                | "Read Pub/Sub Messages" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=pubsub_subscription).with_output_types(bytes)
                | 'Fetch from API 1' >> beam.Map(fetch_1)
                | 'Filter out invalid data' >> beam.Filter(lambda item: item is not None)
                | 'Fetch from API 2' >> beam.Map(fetch_1)
                | 'Filter out invalid data' >> beam.Filter(lambda item: item is not None)
                | 'Parse Article to BQ json' >> beam.Map(parse_to_bq_json)
                | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table='BQ_TABLE_NAME',
                                                               write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                               method=beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.FILE_LOADS,
                                                               triggering_frequency=5
                                                               )
        )
```

Which runs as expected when I run it with DirectRunner but ends with

```
 Job did not reach to a terminal state after waiting indefinitely.
```

Nothing more, nothing less. Docs or other mentions about similar case very limited, so any feedback more than welcome.

Sample from last lines:

```
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.574Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs/_UnpickledSideInput(MapToVoidKey0.out.0)/GroupByKey/WriteStream into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs/_UnpickledSideInput(MapToVoidKey0.out.0)/PairWithVoidKey
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.603Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs/_UnpickledSideInput(MapToVoidKey0.out.0)/GroupByKey/MergeBuckets into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs/_UnpickledSideInput(MapToVoidKey0.out.0)/GroupByKey/ReadStream
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.637Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs/_UnpickledSideInput(MapToVoidKey0.out.0)/Values into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs/_UnpickledSideInput(MapToVoidKey0.out.0)/GroupByKey/MergeBuckets
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.672Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs/_UnpickledSideInput(MapToVoidKey0.out.0)/StreamingPCollectionViewWriter into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForDestinationLoadJobs/_UnpickledSideInput(MapToVoidKey0.out.0)/Values
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.705Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RemoveTempTables/PassTables/PassTables into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/WaitForCopyJobs/WaitForCopyJobs
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.739Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RemoveTempTables/AddUselessValue into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RemoveTempTables/PassTables/PassTables
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.772Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RemoveTempTables/DeduplicateTables/WriteStream into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RemoveTempTables/AddUselessValue
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.822Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RemoveTempTables/DeduplicateTables/MergeBuckets into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RemoveTempTables/DeduplicateTables/ReadStream
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.848Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RemoveTempTables/GetTableNames into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RemoveTempTables/DeduplicateTables/MergeBuckets
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.880Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RemoveTempTables/Delete into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/RemoveTempTables/GetTableNames
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.915Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/ImpulseEmptyPC/FlatMap(<lambda at core.py:3024>) into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/ImpulseEmptyPC/Impulse
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:50.939Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/ImpulseEmptyPC/Map(decode) into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/ImpulseEmptyPC/FlatMap(<lambda at core.py:3024>)
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:51.008Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/Flatten/FlattenReplace/WriteStream into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/TriggerLoadJobsWithTempTables/ParDo(TriggerLoadJobs)/ParDo(TriggerLoadJobs)
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:51.033Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/Flatten/FlattenReplace/WriteStream into WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads/TriggerLoadJobsWithoutTempTables/TriggerLoadJobsWithoutTempTables
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:51.165Z: JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR: Workflow failed.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:51.205Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DETAILED: Cleaning up.
INFO:apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner:2021-01-22T17:27:51.252Z: JOB_MESSAGE_BASIC: Worker pool stopped.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1477, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/XXXX/dev/XXXX/app/app.py", line 151, in <module>
    run(args, pipeline_args)
  File "/Users/XXXX/dev/XXXX/app/app.py", line 108, in run
    p.run().wait_until_finish()
  File "/Users/XXXX/.virtualenvs/app/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 1675, in wait_until_finish
    'Job did not reach to a terminal state after waiting indefinitely.')
AssertionError: Job did not reach to a terminal state after waiting indefinitely.
```

Edit 1: Adding output from console log (unfortunately not much info there):

```
{
textPayload: "Workflow failed."
insertId: "1rtvonbcgg5"
resource: {
type: "dataflow_step"
labels: {
project_id: "437008213460"
job_name: "app-test"
step_id: ""
region: "europe-west1"
job_id: "2021-01-22_11_22_27-2214838125974198028"
}
}
timestamp: "2021-01-22T19:22:37.425862432Z"
severity: "ERROR"
labels: {
dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id: "2021-01-22_11_22_27-2214838125974198028"
dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name: "app-test"
dataflow.googleapis.com/log_type: "system"
dataflow.googleapis.com/region: "europe-west1"
}
logName: "projects/some-project-eu/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message"
receiveTimestamp: "2021-01-22T19:22:39.086520796Z"
}
```

Edit 2: Adding simplified version:

```
def foo(stream_data):
    return str(datetime.now())

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    (
        p
        | "Read Pub/Sub Messages" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=pubsub_subscription).with_output_types(bytes)
        | 'Do foo' >> beam.Map(foo)
        | 'WriteToBigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(table=bq_project + ':' + bq_dataset + '.' + TABLE_NAME,
                                                       schema={"fields": [{"name": "foo_ts", "type": "TIMESTAMP"}]},
                                                       create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                       write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                                       method=beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.FILE_LOADS,
                                                       triggering_frequency=5,
                                                       )
    )
```

and my run commands:

```
streaming_app.py 
  --input_subscription projects/awesome_project/subscriptions/sub-test 
  --runner DataflowRunner 
  --bq_project awesome_project 
  --bq_dataset awesome_dataset 
  --region europe-west1 
  --temp_location gs://awesome-nlp 
  --job_name hope-it-works-test 
  --setup_file ./setup.py 
  --max_num_workers 10
```

Edit 3: Adding also job id of one of the failed jobs: 2021-01-24_06_31_49-168256842937211337

Comment: Can you check Cloud Console to see if there are any additional logs that would point to the error ? (for example, quota errors).

Comment: Unfortunately nothing in console error log (added to my post). Quotas seems to be also green without any issues

Comment: It's strange that the job actually failed. A streaming job should not fail due to BigQuery sink issues (it will just try repeatedly forever) so I guess either you are not running in streaming mode or Dataflow is running into some issue when tying to start your job. Hard to say without looking at the detailed job logs so I suggest contacting Google Cloud Support.

Comment: @miro Which version of python and Apache beam you are using?

Comment: @NirleyGupta, python 3.8 and beam=2.27.0

Comment: does the job get submitted to Dataflow?

Comment: Yes, but it dies right after that (I get job-id / edit 3)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try comparing your code with sample Dataflow runner code given over [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436564/apache-beam-io-bigquerysource-use-standard-sql-not-working-when-running-as-dataf/65437789#65437789). As I cannot see your complete code, but if you try to fit your code over sample given above, It will run over Dataflow runner.

EDIT 1:

Please find below a working example:-

```
#------------Import Lib-----------------------#
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import window
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions
import os, sys, time
import argparse
import logging
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from datetime import datetime

#------------Set up BQ parameters-----------------------#
# Replace with Project Id
project = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
Pubsub_subscription='projects/xxxxxxxxxxx/subscriptions/Pubsubdemo_subscription'
#plitting Of Records----------------------#

class Transaction_ECOM(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        logging.info(element)

        result = json.loads(element)
        data_bkt = result.get('_bkt','null')
        data_cd=result.get('_cd','null')
        data_indextime=result.get('_indextime','0')
        data_kv=result.get('_kv','null')
        data_raw=result['_raw']
        data_raw1=data_raw.replace("\n", "")
        data_serial=result.get('_serial','null')
        data_si = str(result.get('_si','null'))
        data_sourcetype =result.get('_sourcetype','null')
        data_subsecond = result.get('_subsecond','null')
        data_time=result.get('_time','null')
        data_host=result.get('host','null')
        data_index=result.get('index','null')
        data_linecount=result.get('linecount','null')
        data_source=result.get('source','null')
        data_sourcetype1=result.get('sourcetype','null')
        data_splunk_server=result.get('splunk_server','null')

        return [{"datetime_indextime": time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(int(data_indextime))), "_bkt": data_bkt, "_cd": data_cd,  "_indextime": data_indextime,  "_kv": data_kv,  "_raw": data_raw1,  "_serial": data_serial,  "_si": data_si, "_sourcetype": data_sourcetype, "_subsecond": data_subsecond, "_time": data_time, "host": data_host, "index": data_index, "linecount": data_linecount, "source": data_source, "sourcetype": data_sourcetype1, "splunk_server": data_splunk_server}]



def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)


    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, streaming=True)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
    p1 = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)



    data_loading = (
        p1
        | "Read Pub/Sub Messages" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=Pubsub_subscription)

    )


    project_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    dataset_id = 'test123'
    table_schema_ECOM = ('datetime_indextime:DATETIME, _bkt:STRING, _cd:STRING, _indextime:STRING, _kv:STRING, _raw:STRING, _serial:STRING, _si:STRING, _sourcetype:STRING, _subsecond:STRING, _time:STRING, host:STRING, index:STRING, linecount:STRING, source:STRING, sourcetype:STRING, splunk_server:STRING')

        # Persist to BigQuery
        # WriteToBigQuery accepts the data as list of JSON objects

#---------------------Index = ITF----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    result = (
    data_loading
        | 'Clean-ITF' >> beam.ParDo(Transaction_ECOM())
        | 'Write-ITF' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                                    table='CFF_ABC',
                                                    dataset=dataset_id,
                                                    project=project_id,
                                                    schema=table_schema_ECOM,
                                                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
                                                    ))

    result = p1.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  path_service_account = '/home/vibhg/Splunk/CFF/xxxxxxxxxxx-abcder125.json'
  os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = path_service_account
  run()
```

It has few additional libraries so just ignore it.

Some key features which are :-

1. Set 'streaming' as 'True'
2. Subscription name should be of format ''projects/>xxxxxxxxxxx>/subscriptions/>subscription name>''

Sample data which is published on topic, that will be captured from Subscription is given below:-

```
{"_bkt": "A1E8-A5370FECA146", "_cd": "412:140787687", "_indextime": "1611584940", "_kv": "1", "_raw": "2021-01-25 14:28:59,126 INFO  [com.abcd.mfs.builder.builders.BsLogEntryBuilder] [-] LogEntryType=\"BsCall\", fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\", BusinessServiceName=\"BsSalesOrderCreated\", Locality=\"NA\", Success=\"True\", BsExecutionTime=\"00:00:00.005\", OrderNo=\"374941817\", Locality=\"NA\" , [fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\"], [bsName=\"BsSalesOrderCreated\"], [userId=\"s-oitp-u-global\"], [userIdRegion=\"NA\"], [msgId=\"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccc\"], [msgIdSeq=\"2\"], [originator=\"ISOM\"] ", "_serial": "0", "_si": ["9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1", "itf"], "_sourcetype": "BBClog", "_subsecond": ".126", "_time": "2021-01-25 14:28:59.126 UTC", "host": "shampo-lx4821.abcd.com", "index": "itf", "linecount": "1", "source": "/opt/VRE/WebSphere/lickserv/profiles/appsrv01/logs/na-ebtree02_srv/log4j2.log", "sourcetype": "BBClog", "web_server": "9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1"}
[vibhg@aiclassificationdev8 jobrun]$ head -2 ITF_202101251435
{"_bkt": "itf~412~2EE5428B-7CEA-4C49-A1E8-A5370FECA146", "_cd": "412:140787687", "_indextime": "1611584940", "_kv": "1", "_raw": "2021-01-25 14:28:59,126 INFO  [com.abcd.mfs.builder.builders.BsLogEntryBuilder] [-] LogEntryType=\"BsCall\", fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\", BusinessServiceName=\"BsSalesOrderCreated\", Locality=\"NA\", Success=\"True\", BsExecutionTime=\"00:00:00.005\", OrderNo=\"374941817\", Locality=\"NA\" , [fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\"], [bsName=\"BsSalesOrderCreated\"], [userId=\"s-oitp-u-global\"], [userIdRegion=\"NA\"], [msgId=\"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbcccc\"], [msgIdSeq=\"2\"], [originator=\"ISOM\"] ", "_serial": "0", "_si": ["9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1", "itf"], "_sourcetype": "BBClog", "_subsecond": ".126", "_time": "2021-01-25 14:28:59.126 UTC", "host": "shampo-lx4821.abcd.com", "index": "itf", "linecount": "1", "source": "/opt/VRE/WebSphere/lickserv/profiles/appsrv01/logs/na-ebtree02_srv/log4j2.log", "sourcetype": "BBClog", "web_server": "9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1"}
{"_bkt": "9-A1E8-A5370FECA146", "_cd": "412:140787671", "_indextime": "1611584940", "_kv": "1", "_raw": "2021-01-25 14:28:58,659 INFO  [com.abcd.mfs.builder.builders.BsLogEntryBuilder] [-] LogEntryType=\"BsCall\", fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\", BusinessServiceName=\"BsCreateOrderV2\", BsExecutionTime=\"00:00:01.568\", OrderNo=\"374942155\", CountryCode=\"US\", ClientSystem=\"owfe-webapp\" , [fulName=\"EBCMFSSALES02\"], [bsName=\"BsCreateOrderV2\"], [userId=\"s-salja1-u-irssemal\"], [userIdRegion=\"NA\"], [msgId=\"6652311fece28966\"], [msgIdSeq=\"25\"], [originator=\"SellingApi\"] ", "_serial": "1", "_si": ["9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1", "itf"], "_sourcetype": "BBClog", "_subsecond": ".659", "_time": "2021-01-25 14:28:58.659 UTC", "host": "shampo-lx4821.abcd.com", "index": "itf", "linecount": "1", "source": "/opt/VRE/WebSphere/lickserv/profiles/appsrv01/logs/na-ebtree02_srv/log4j2.log", "sourcetype": "BBClog", "web_server": "9ttr-bfc-gcp-europe-besti1"}
```

You can execute script with following command :-

```
python script.py --region europe-west1 --project xxxxxxx --temp_location gs://temp/temp --runner DataflowRunner --job_name name
```

As It looks like you have missed to set Streaming parameter in your code.

Comment: Code works fine as DirectRunner but ending in error after I push it with DataFlowRunner. If I change the last pipeline step to STREAMING_INSERTS everything works fine as Direct or Dataflow run. 
Before the error I can just see bunch of ''Fusing consumer WriteToBigQuery/BigQueryBatchFileLoads'' logs (no errors).
One thing to mention is that the table I'm trying to write is partitioned by Timestamp of one field

Comment: If i understand correctly, by adding  STREAMING_INSERTS to pipeline its is running perfectly both as Direct & Dataflow runner ? Your problem is solved ?

Comment: No, problem is that I can't figure out the problem described above when running WriteToBigQuery in FILE_LOADS mode.  
Reason why I'm after FILE_LOADS is that STREAMING_INSERTS does not allow inserts to partitioned table outside of 1825-366 date range (what I'm trying to handle).

Comment: Added simplified code as Edit 2 (thanks for trying to help btw)

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't get time today to work over code. I will work over code share with you by tomorrow.

Comment: @miro I have added a working example which reads data from a Pubsub subscription and load it to BQ table. job will be running on streaming and loading data to BQ as soon as data is published to Topic. You can customize code as per your requirement as this code is Dataflow runner code.

Comment: thank you again, but getting exactly the same behaviour. Runs ok as DirectRunner but DataFlowRunner returns:

  File "/Users/miro/.virtualenvs/diox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/dataflow_runner.py", line 1656, in wait_until_finish
    assert duration or terminated, (
AssertionError: Job did not reach to a terminal state after waiting indefinitely.

Specifically this line returns 'False'
terminated = self.is_in_terminal_state() (dataflow_runner.py", line 1656)

Comment: Just adding that the job fails after adding to WriteToBigQuery to following:

method=beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.FILE_LOADS,
triggering_frequency=5

Comment: If i understand correctly, You have added 'triggering_frequency=5' to my code and it fail. But 'triggering_frequency'  don't work on Streaming pipeline. It work on batch load. So avoid using this parameter. You can refer following case as a reference to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723619/triggering-frequency-can-only-be-used-with-file-loads-method-of-writing-to-bigqu

Comment: I have added also 'method=beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.FILE_LOADS', which uses the triggering_frequency property

Comment: As this is kind of a known error, then why you wanted to introduce 'triggering_frequency', as your end requirement is to have a streaming Dataflow job which should perform streaming and code which i have shared with you is a working code doing same.

Comment: afaik streaming should support also FILE_LOADS together with triggering_frequency