# How to parse 2 json files in Apache beam

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, apache-beam, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I have 2 json configuration files to read and want to assign there values to variables. I am creating a data flow job using apache beam but unable to parse those files and assign there values to a variable.

`config1.json - { "bucket_name": "mybucket"}`
`config2.json - { "dataset_name": "mydataset"}`

This is the pipeline statements ---- **I tried with one JSON file first but even that is not working**

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        steps = (pipeline
                | "Getdata" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(custom_options.configfile)
                | "CUSTOM JSON PARSE" >> beam.ParDo(custom_json_parser(custom_options.configfile))
                | "write to GCS" >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://mynewbucket/outputfile.txt')
            )
    result = pipeline.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()
```

I also tried creating a function to parse atleast one file. This is a sample method I created but it did not work.

````
class custom_json_parser(beam.DoFn):
    import apache_beam as beam
    from apache_beam.io.gcp import gcsio
    import logging
    def __init__(self, configfile):
        self.configfile = configfile
    def process(self, configfile):
        logging.info("JSON PARSING STARTED")
        with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(self.configfile, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                data = json.loads(line)
                bucket = data.get('bucket_name')
        dataset = data.get('dataset_name') ```
        
  Can someone please suggest the best method to resolve this issue in apache beam?

Thanks in Advance
````

Comment: Is the pipeline read several time those file? Or can you read them only once at the beginning and execute the whole pipeline with those parameters?

Comment: I want to read them only once at the beginning and execute the whole pipeline

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read only once your files in the pipeline, don't read them in the pipeline, but before running it.

- Read the files from GCS
- Parse the file and put the useful content in the pipeline options map
- Run your pipeline and use the data from the options

---

**EDIT 1**

You can use this piece of code to load the file and read it, before your pipeline. Simple Python, standard GCS libraries.

```
    from google.cloud import storage
    import json

    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket('your-bucket')
    blob = bucket.get_blob("name.json")

    json_data = blob.download_as_string().decode('UTF-8')
    print(json_data) # print -> {"name": "works!!"}
    print(json.loads(json_data)["name"]) # print -> works!!
```

Comment: I am facing the issue in 2nd point only - Parse the file and put the useful content in the pipeline options map. I am unable to parse them

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code snippet: -

Function to Parse File

```
class custom_json_parser(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        logging.info(element)
        data = json.loads(element)        
        bucket = data.get('bucket_name')
        dataset = data.get('dataset_name')
        return [{"bucket": bucket , "dataset": dataset }]
```

Over Pipeline you can call function

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        steps = (pipeline
                | "Getdata" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(custom_options.configfile)
                | "CUSTOM JSON PARSE" >> beam.ParDo(custom_json_parser())
                | "write to GCS" >> beam.io.WriteToText('gs://mynewbucket/outputfile.txt')
            )
    result = pipeline.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()
```

It will work.

Comment: I am facing below error while running the above code 
line 64, in process File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end) RuntimeError: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 16 (char 15) [while running 'CUSTOM JSON PARSE']

Comment: Here you can see a working example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65850110/dataflow-bigquery-file-loads-job-did-not-reach-to-a-terminal-state-after-wait/65856630#65856630  Just Replace 'ReadFromPubSub' with 'ReadFromText' try to fit in your snippet over same.